# Is it possible to use notation [] with pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, notation

I declare a matrix of integer using malloc():

```
int *m;
m = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

Can I use array notation [] to select an element from matrix?

For example:
I use `*(m+1)` to select the second element of matrix m.
Can I select the second element of matrix m through this notation: `m[1]`?

Comment: Yes. Please, next time, try before asking....

Comment: All that is "*declare*"d in the code you show is a pointer to `int`, namely `m`.

Comment: @MichelBillaud: Where?

Comment: Has been fixed in the mean time you posted. Comment deleted.

Comment: Yes, its possible. However this only works for on-diminsional matrices (arrays). For two dimensional matrices its trickier

Comment: @MichelBillaud: Please be careful with this advice.  "Try it and see" is responsible for all too many false lessons.  For example, if you want to know what `i = i++` does, "try it and see" is just about guaranteed to give you the **wrong** answer.  In Carmine's case, we might say "Please, next time, read any basic introduction to pointers before asking."

Comment: @SteveSummit I am! And the question here is specifically about syntax. Not undefined behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. However, if you are specifying it as a static size, you may as well do `int m[10]` in your declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a+i)`, so yes, the `[]` subscript operator works with array and pointer expressions.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initilialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So, for an array `a`, if you write `a[i]`, the *expression* `a` is converted from an array type to a pointer type, and the `[]` operator is applied to the resulting pointer expression.  For a pointer `p`, no conversion is necessary, and the `[]` operator is applied to `p` directly.